# Dynamic query using LinqKit is so slow! Can a stored procedure be better in that case?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, linqkit

I am using LinqKit to build a query using dynamically generated filters.

That query fetches a quite large object graph from the database to perform calculations and does some other modifications to that data. As long as I don't use `Includes` in my query, it doesn't take long to get the main entity I need from the database. But, unfortunately, **I need many of it's related entities** to perform the needed calculations.

Each time I am adding an `Include`, this translates into a new **nested subquery** in SQL. I have about 8 or 9 `Inlcudes` so this translates to **a lot** of nested subqueries. That queries takes forever to return the data.

I would like all these nested subqueries to disappear from the SQL, but it's kinda tough to shape the SQL just the way I want using LinqKit from the application side.

I thought that, for that specific case, it would be a good idea to write a **stored procedure** just the way I want the SQL to be, and call it from Entity Framework.

My problem is I don't know how to get the **object graph** on the application side using a stored procedure. I can make EF generate a `ComplexType` which will include all the data in a single "entity", but the code doing calculation awaits a **specific entity object graph** (the main entity and it's related entities) so that code has no idea what that `ComplexType` is. I really don't want to have to rewrite the calculation engine to use that `ComplexType`. I can map the result to a single Entity, but only **that** Entity will be returned. I want the related entities to be returned too.

Looks like I'm caught between a rock and a crazy place.

Can anybody suggest anything ?

Comment: https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#more-optimized-queries

Answer (score 0):

We had the similar problems too. We end up building SQL views, and query against the views instead. I also think it's idea from CQRS pattern, basically, you separate your read model from write model.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've thought about querying views too, but since my calculation engine needs that specific object graph, how could I map the queried view to what the engine expects as entity graph ?

Comment: Can it be computed in a back-end service? Sometimes, if there is computation involved, you can do it on a backend service and put it in a query table.

Comment: Sadly, all the computation is made application-side. It's a LOT of code and it would be too much of a burden to rewrite it. That's why I would like to know of alternatives to fetch the needed object graph.